# How to attach geth to a parity node with admin?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity

I have installed two nodes under PoA using Parity.

I normally use this to attached geth to a geth node:

```
geth attach node/geth.ipc
```

I got working geth attach using rpc but there is no admin.

```
geth attach http://localhost:8540
```

But then I get no admin. I entered the admin into the toml file and the node fails to start.

Is there a way to get this working so that the admin functionality in geth can be used when attached to a parity node?

Answer (score 6):

If you mean you get:

```
> admin
ReferenceError: admin is not defined
```

Then this might be caused because it is not running with the admin module enabled. Make sure you enable it by adding it to the --http.api list. Eg. `--http.api debug,eth,web3,personal,net,admin`.